# How to successfully initialize an RTCPeerConnection in Expo managed React-Native app

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, webrtc

Can't initialize an *RTCPeerConnection* without getting: **TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'WebRTCModule.peerConnectionInit')** in Expo managed React-Native app. This is for streaming an interactive chat service with users using an Expo plugin.

Here is the line of code the error originates:

```
let testServer = [
        { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }
      ]

myPC = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: testServer });
```

Tried the following:

1. Adding required android permissions in Android Manifest
2. Bumping minSDKVersion in android build.gradle from '21' to '24'.
3. Adding compileOptions to app build.gradle for sourceCompatibility: JavaVersion 1.8 and targetCompatibility: JavaVersion 11
4. Added **-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }** to proguard-rules.pro.
5. Added **android.minSdkVersion=24** to gradle.properties
6. Npm installed **"react-native-webrtc": "^1.106.1"**, ensured compatibility with  **"expo": "~47.0.14"**, and **"react-native": "0.70.8"**.
7. Added **"@config-plugins/react-native-webrtc"** to my app.json.
8. Running **npx expo prebuild**
9. Running **./gradlew clean** from android directory.

Was expecting to successfully execute: `myPC = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}] });`. But instead get the aforementioned error. Help!